# Mongo query to find all records where attribute is not an empty string

Tags: mongodb

Trying to find all records where attribute is not an empty string.

```
db.player.find({name: {$not: ''}})
```

gives the error:

```
error: {
    "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue $not needs a regex or a document",
    "code" : 17287
}
```

Do i have to use a regex to do this or is there a simpler way to check for empty strings using mongo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`$ne`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/#op._S_ne) for this:

```js
db.player.find({name: {$ne: ''}})
```